# Any default converters for WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

i read that i can use data converters in binding like ...

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PositionConverter}}" />
```

from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bencon/archive/2006/05/10/594886.aspx)

but i wonder if there are any "in-built" converters. because creating converters to just output say 2 decimal places etc seem troublesome. i just thought that there must be sometime inbuilt that i can use?

Comment: Not a list of built-in converters, but since .NET 3.5 there is also a FormatString property on the binding class, which can be used for simple formating (e.g. 2 decimal places)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a list of built-in converters, see commanderz's answer

> creating converters to just output say 2 decimal places etc seem troublesome

Indeed, and you don't need to ;)

Instead, you can use the [`StringFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx) property to specify a format specifier:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeValue, StringFormat=F2}" />
```

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbxft59x.aspx) for details on formatting and lists of valid format specifiers.

Answer (score 9):

[Here is the list of all converters provided by the framework](http://asimsajjad.blogspot.com/2010/05/built-in-wpf-ivalueconverters.html)

Comment: +1 Nice. Are they already instantiated at any point with a known (and stable) resource-key so that they can be used without declaring them newly in xaml?

Comment: I don't think so, but I guess you can instantiate them in app.xaml once and have them available in whole app.

Comment: @commanderz: Yes, this is also more reliable in case of the keys will be changed in further versions of the fcl. Thanks.